Approach to use Flux Image Update Automation Kind?
I'm using currently fluxv2 image update automation to automatically detect whenever there is new images for my workloads and apply the change in the deployment manifests and push it to the cluster.
The structure that is used is:
base/
  workload1/
    deployment.yaml
    imageupdateautomation.yaml
    ...
    kustomization.yaml
  workload2/
    deployment.yaml
    service.yaml
    imageupdateautomation.yaml
    ...
    kustomization.yaml
  ...
test-environment/
    workload1/
      kustomization.yaml
      deployment.patch.yaml
      imagepolicy.yaml
      ...
    workload2/
      kustomization.yaml
      deployment.patch.yaml
      imagepolicy.yaml
      ...
    kustomization.yaml
prod-environment/
  ...


It is possible to see that we have 1 folder per environment, where each folder has each workload, and we have a base configuration in the base folder. For each workload we have configured a Image Update Automation. According to documentation this component will enable the scan of the entire namespace searching for image policies.
I didn't found any thing mentioning if Image Update Automation kind should be configured per namespace or per workload, I'd expect to have some recommendation, but was unable to find it on flux documentation.
My question: what are the es approach and why?
